# Retrieve functions from a global variable

Tags: php

Is it possible to retrieve all the functions included in a global variable?

I'm using a very complex plugin (not written by me) that call the functions in this way:

```
$GLOBALS['myplugin']->member->isActive()
```

Is there a way to retreive all the functions of `$GLOBALS['myplugin']->member`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find some success with [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php), passing in the name of the class that `member` is an instance of, or the object instance itself.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I'm looking for.
Is there a way to retrieve also the arguments of a function? I'm trying to do a reverse enginering of a script...
For example, I know there is a function called $GLOBALS['myplugin']->member->login() but I don't know which and how many arguments I need to pass to the function

Comment: @Pennywise83 Have a look at the [Function Handling Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php).